# How to select records containing a string (starting from the first element)

Tags: r

I need to select only records containing a string, starting from the first element but I do not want to use `substring` because I should indicate the number of digits.
I tried to use `grep/grepl` and ^(for starting from the first element) but my problem is that I have an external vector where grep should look.
There's an example:

```
hello <- c("720", "555", "556")

A$1 %in% substring(hello,1,3)
```

This works as I wish but I don't want to use `substring` because I do not want to indicate the number of digits.
I'd like to use grep in someway:

```
grep(^hello, A$1)
```

Of course this doesn't work.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks
Sabrina

Comment: Probably you are looking for `grepl(paste0("^", hello, collapse = "|"), A$ColumnName)`

Comment: Exactly! Thanks Ronak